# Property and Attribute meaning difference in RDF/OWL

Tags: rdf, terminology, owl, ontology, rdfs

In RDF/OWL, the meaning of property and attribute are same, or is it different?

Answer (score 6):

In both RDF and OWL, a *property* is an URI used to link a subject URI with an object, which can be a URI or a literal. OWL additionally distinguishes between object, annotation and datatype property. The latter comes close to the meaning of *attribute* used in Object Orientation and relational algebra. However, there is no use of the term *attribute* in RDF and OWL.